# dyld: Library not loaded Swift 2.0

Tags: cocoapods, swift2

I updated my project to Swift 2.0 which ultimately meant one of my libraries stopped working. I deleted it and ran `pod update`.

When trying to boot the app on a device I get this error

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Charts.framework/Charts   Referenced
>   from:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3563EB7F-CC1D-4BEA-BCA5-A2A8F3F6DA39/VisitsToDo.app/VisitsToDo
>   Reason: image not found

If I run the app on the simulator it gives this error.

> ld: framework not found Charts
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

`Charts` is the pod that I previously deleted and I can't find out where the reference to it is stored? I have tried deleting and reinstalling all pods but this doesn't solve the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be unique to my project but I had to remove `linker flags` related to `Chart` in my app `Build Settings`